# iOS Safari: Frequently sent ajax calls sometimes not reaching the server

Tags: ios, ajax, asp.net-mvc, safari, request

After searching now for hours, I unfortunately can't find a solution to my current iOS Safari issue.

I've got a JavaScript frontent which uses jQuery.ajax to communicate with an ASP.NET MVC web server.

That works absolutely perfect on all platforms, e.g. Windows 10 with Chrome, Firefox, IE (yes, IE works), Edge. Or on a Mac with Chrome, Firefox, Safari. The place where it does **not** work is iOS Safari.

In my scenario, I'm sending multiple AJAX requests to the server almost at the same time. Maybe 3 to maximum 6 calls. Having a look at the Safari developer tools, the calls look like this.

[image: DeveloperTools]

They seem to take very long, but having a look at the server, they appearently never reach the backend. Also, after exactly 10 minutes, the browser runs into the timeout. Even though I have configured an AJAX timeout of 60 seconds.

My code looks pretty okay to me at the moment (written in TypeScript):

```
let defer: JQueryDeferred<any> = jQuery.Deferred();
this._RunningRequests++;

let settings: JQueryAjaxSettings = {
    method: method,
    url: this.BuildURL(controller, action, id),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    timeout: Timeout,
    cache: false,
    headers: {}
};

if (payload) {
    settings.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
}

jQuery.ajax(settings)
    .done((result: any) => {
        if (this.DetectLogoutRedirect(result)) {
            defer.reject();
            location.reload(true);
            return;
        }

        defer.resolve(result);
    })
    .fail((jqXHR: JQueryXHR, textStatus: string, errorThrown: string) => {
        defer.reject();
        this.HandleError(method, controller, action, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }).always(() => {
        this._RunningRequests--;
    });

return defer.promise();
```

Here now the fun part. As soon as I add a delay to the call ...

```
let delay = this._RunningRequests * 500;
setTimeout(() => { jQuery.ajax(...) }, delay);
```

... which makes sure the calls are not sent quickly after each other, it works perfectly fine.

Things I've tried and found out so far:

- I've set all headers for cache control plus all jQuery configurations adressing cache to false
- I've added a guid-like param to every call (POST as well) to ensure the URL is always unique
- As mentioned above, I've added the delay which solves the problem, but is not realy practiable
- I've tried to reproduce the issue wihin the iOS Simulator. Same result.
- It seems to affect POST requests only, but I'm not sure about that.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you find any resolution/fix/answer to this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not ...

Comment: 2022 and I'm wondering if you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Still no, sorry :\

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same issue with our Single Page App as soon as it got particulary "chatty" with our API.

It appears to be caused by a bug with the DNS resolution somewhere in the iOS networking stack.

We found that by changing the DNS setting from automatic to manual on the device, and setting the DNS servers to the Google Public DNS, all XHR requests made by our app worked and we stopped getting the weird timeouts.

Here is a guide on how to change the DNS setting on an iOS device:
https://www.macinstruct.com/tutorials/how-to-change-your-iphones-dns-servers/